# Clicking On View Post In Draft Opens New Tab

Tags: wp-admin, draft

Since 4.0, when you save a post as a Draft the View Post link opens the saved post in a new tab. (target ="_blank")

Is there a way to revert back to the previous behaviour (which was to open the Preview version in the -same- tab?

What's weird is that once the post is published, the saved version opens in the same tab (as in previous WP versions.)

I looked at this post (which seems to be the reverse) [Make “Post published. View post” Open in a New Tab](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173819/make-post-published-view-post-open-in-a-new-tab)

I found that by editing line 93 from:

```
10 => sprintf( __('Post draft updated. <a href="%s">Preview post</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', $permalink ) ) ),
```

to

```
10 => sprintf( __('Post draft updated. <a href="%s">Preview post</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'false', $permalink ) ) ),
```

That does what I want. HOWEVER, that's hacking the core. Is there a way to modify this WITHOUT hacking this file?

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack by adding below lines in your theme's functions.php file.

```
function remove_preview_target()
{
    // below JS code will set Preview button's **target** attribute to **_self**, it means same tab/window.
    echo "<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#post-preview').attr('target', '_self');
        })
        </script>";

}
// this action performs in admit footer
add_action('admin_footer', 'remove_preview_target');
```

Or add below lines in your JS file.

```
jQuery(document) . ready(function () {
     jQuery("#post-preview") . attr("target", "_self");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified your answer slightly to indicate that one has to enqueue the JS in the admin separately from the 'regular' pages.